# Fit the image preview on a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slide, image-gallery

I'll try to explain what I want to do :) Here's a picture with a little sketch.
[image: Sketch]

This is what I did for the moment, but I got stuck. I'm using Bootstrap 3.

I want to make the "Image00/01/02 - Thumbnails" move to the Preview box, I did it, but I don't know how to make the box with that size and keep the images "responsive" to the box size, and when you click on the "Preview" box, the images go to full screen to view the full size and quality.

HTML

```
<div class="container" id="portfolio">
    <div class="col-md-12">




        <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1200px">
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/image0.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/image1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="img/image2.jpg" style="width:100%">

            <div class="w3-row-padding w3-section">
                <div class="w3-col s4">
                    <img class="demo w3-border w3-hover-shadow" src="img/image0.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(1)">
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col s4">
                    <img class="demo w3-border w3-hover-shadow" src="img/image1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(2)">
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col s4">
                    <img class="demo w3-border w3-hover-shadow" src="img/image2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(3)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




    </div>
</div>


<script>

    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentDiv(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-border-red";
    }

</script>
```

And here's the CSS

```
/* COL-MD-12 */

.col-md-12 { height: 550px; background-color: #fff; text-align: center; margin-top: -20px; padding-top: 45px; }

/* COL-MD-4 

#img1 { height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: #333; color: #fff; margin-left: 80px; }
#img01 { height: 200px; width: 200px; position: center; } */
```

Here's an update from the code:

```
<div class="container" id="portfolio">
    <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="w3-content">
                <div id="containerSlider">
                    <img class="mySlides" src="img/image0.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides" src="img/image1.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides" src="img/image2.jpg" style="width:100%">
                </div>

                <div id="containerThumbnails">    
                    <div class="w3-row-padding w3-section">
                        <div class="w3-col s4">
                            <img class="demo w3-border w3-hover-shadow" src="img/image0.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(1)">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-col s4">
                            <img class="demo w3-border w3-hover-shadow" src="img/image1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(2)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-col s4">
                            <img class="demo w3-border w3-hover-shadow" src="img/image2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(3)">
                        </div>
                </div>    

                </div>
    </div>

</div>


<script>

    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentDiv(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-border-red";
    }

</script>
```

CSS

```
/* Container_Slider */

#containerSlider { height: 219px; width: 897px; background-color: #333; display: inline-block; }
#containerThumbnails { height: 122px; width: 242px; background-color: #333; display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the images responsive to the box size, use `width: 100%` on the images.

Comment: I did it, but the images expand more than the box I want :S
How can I set a box like 350x700 px, and the image `responsive` inside the box?

Comment: Are your images positioned absolute? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17529984/2397550